# in MySQL, how to I work around it not being able to use defined strings as an index?

Tags: mysql

Thinking the approach would be to create a hash of the string at a fixed length and then index the hash. If so, is there a way to do this within MySQL, or does it require me to do some parts of the process outside of MySQL.

Database engine is InnoDB and here's info on the error I'm getting that appears to be on target.

http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1185285.htm

Basically trying to use a column that is a natural longtext key as a [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp), meaning that an insert transaction is rolled back if the column field is not unique. The column can be 80 to 150 thousand characters in length.

Comment: Are you referring to a ENUM ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Or FULLTEXT search ?  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @superfro: Nope, not ENUM. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `UNIQUE` indexes on `TEXT/LONGTEXT/BLOB` fields are not a good idea as MySQL is not capable of having an arbitrary length index.  You either have to specify a maximum number of characters (eg. `UNIQUE (fieldname(255))` - I believe 4005 is the current limit for UTF8, 1000 regular), limiting the field length (in which case you might as well make it a `VARCHAR`), or remove the `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: Right, I know it's not a good idea, looking for a work around. For example, creating a hash of the text. Limiting the field to the first XX chars is not an option, since it would be meaningless.

Comment: @blunders When I have to do this, I do use a hash for the purpose as `UNIQUE` indexes are not an option.

Comment: Okay, thank. So does MySQL have a way to take a column create a hash and store it as another hash, or do I need to do this in the application layer? Guess this would all have to be within one transaction as well, since if the record exist the transaction would need to be rooled back.

Comment: @blunders: Sorry for the delay, went AFK.  `MD5()` and `SHA1()` functions are available (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/encryption-functions.html), wrap them around the content on `INSERT`, or most likely quicker given the query length, use an `UPDATE` with one of the hash functions on the field within a transaction.  Performing the hash on the application layer and using it in the `INSERT` would be easiest I would think.  If you put a `UNIQUE` on the hash field, that will have the desired effect.